# То, что объявлено внутри тела оператора if, не считается объявленным вне этого тела

Tags: c++

Есть класс. Мне нужно по условию создать объект(ы), вызвав один из его конструкторов (несколько условий, несколько конструкторов). Но, как сказано в заголовке, то, что объявлено внутри тела оператора `if`, не считается объявленным вне этого тела.

Таким образом: если условие срабатывает, то я создаю объект класса, вызывая нужный мне конструктор, и внутри тела этого условия могу работать с этим объектом, всё пока что замечательно.

НО как только я пытаюсь поработать с этим объектом ВНЕ тела `if`, объект оказывается необъявленным. В итоге, работать я с ним не могу. И с обычными переменными тоже так же, но это не важно.

Приходится заранее создавать объекты (например, самым простым конструктором), а потом по `if` они заново объявляются с нужным мне конструктором, и код запускается, но работает неправильно. Объект никак не меняется.

(и долго будет переделывать всё так, чтобы он по условию просто менялся, а не именно создавался с нужным конструктором, и это очень нежелательный вариант).

Я пробовал в начале после объявления объекта сразу его удалить/очистить/вызвать деструктор, но, как ни крути, нормально прога не работала.

Как это выглядит конкретно в коде:

```
int main ()
{
/*1*/КЛАСС объект1, объект2;
//Тут могут быть попытки сразу эти классы удалить/очистить/вызвать деструкто
if (условие)
   {КЛАСС объект1(параметры нужного конструктора);
   Вывод объекта1;  //Всё хорошо!
   }
if (другое условие) 
   {КЛАСС объект2(параметры нужного конструктора);
   Вывод объекта2;  //Всё хорошо!
   }

if (ещё одно условие)
/*
   создание 1 или 2 объекта
*/

/*
...
*/

Вывод объекта1; //Выводит неправильно, ибо внутри этого объекта записано не то, 
//что мне нужно, а непонятно что
Вывод объекта2; //Если же я убираю строчку /*1*/, то, как сказано в заголовке,
//работать с объектами 1 и 2 я уже не могу. Компилятор говорит, что они не описаны.

return 0;
}
```

**Скажите, пожалуйста**:

ИЛИ как создавать объект в теле `if` так, чтобы он считался описанным в `main` и я мог с ним работать (думаю, нужно приписать какое-то нужное слово перед созданием объекта в теле `if`, но какое???),

ИЛИ как мне в начале, после /*1*/, удалить/очистить/вызвать деструктор объектов 1 и 2 так, чтобы потом они в теле `if` заново нормально создавались с нужными мне конструкторами, и при этом потом я мог нормально с ними потом работать, а не видеть какой-то бред в объектах. Или просто сделать нормальный деструктор, и просто его вызывать.

P.S. Думаю, это не играет особой роли в этой проблеме, т.к. она довольно обще описана, но класс состоит из `int`-массива 5x5 и ещё одной `int`, и несколькими конструкторами для нужного заполнения этого массива при создании, несколькими методов, несколькими перегрузками операторов, в общем, ничего необычного. И пока что вызвав после /*1*/ деструктор, в котором одна строчка - `delete [] int_массив_5x5`, я добился, что в объект записывается то, что нужно - кроме первых двух столбцов, в которых какой-то бред.

Comment: @Aftorik, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смотрите.

Сначала о том, что у вас происходит.

Если вы внутри блока объявляете объект с таким же именем, как и вне блока, то внутри блока вы работаете только с этим новым объектом, а снаружи — снова со старым. То есть конструктор ничего со старым блоком не делает.

Теперь о том, что нужно сделать. Сразу вопрос: а имеет ли смысл работать с объектом, если вы не сконструировали его? Ну то есть, со случаем конструктора по умолчанию? Если нет, то вся работа должна быть внутри `if`'а, вот и проблема решена.

Если вам всё же необходимо «вынести» объект из блока, заведите указатель на этот объект (не забудьте инициализировать его!), и выделяйте объект в heap'е при помощи `new`. Не забудьте уничтожить объект, когда он вам будет более не нужен. (Если знаете, что такое смарт-пойнтер, имеет смысл воспользоваться им.)

Comment: Спасибо! Да, как раз через указатель и {new} получилось сделать!

Comment: @Aftorik: Пожалуйста!